# how to make two elements to be in the same line - html css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div class="{{($type != 'forecast')?'col-md-8':'col-md-8'}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="12" {{($viewOnly)?'disabled':''}} >
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="test"></i>
    </div>                                 
</div>
```

this is the UI
[image]

I just want the `<i>` icon be next to the input field and not in the bottom.

How I can achieve that?

Comment: What you want is what would display if you didn't use any CSS at all. Also you need to fix your `label`, it is not attached to the following input. You can achieve that by either wrapping the input in the label, or giving the input an `id` and refer that in a `for`attribute on the label.

Comment: @connexo this is Bootstrap, not using any CSS will lead to loss in default BS's style, sir.

Comment: @OMiShah That was not a recommendation as of what to do; it was a hint that OP needs a Bootstrap solution as BS is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `input` field and the `icon` within a div with the class [input-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/input-group/).

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="12" {{($viewOnly)?'disabled':''}}>
   <i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="test"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx this solved it

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <div class="input-group" style="display: flex">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="12" {{($viewOnly)?'disabled':''}} >
     <i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="test"></i>
 </div>  
</div>
```